# How to create a Worker with parameters for in WorkManager for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

Android architecture has a new components [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/).

From the [example](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics),

```
class CompressWorker(context : Context, params : WorkerParameters)
    : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        // Do the work here--in this case, compress the stored images.
        // In this example no parameters are passed; the task is
        // assumed to be "compress the whole library."
        myCompress()

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.SUCCESS

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)

    }

}

val compressionWork = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CompressWorker>().build()
```

How can I create a `Worker` that accept parameters in constructor or `doWork`?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use `setInputData` method to send data just like Bundle.

```
/***  Logic to set Data while creating worker **/
val compressionWork = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(CompressWorker::class.java)
val data = Data.Builder()
//Add parameter in Data class. just like bundle. You can also add Boolean and Number in parameter.
data.putString("file_path", "put_file_path_here")
//Set Input Data
compressionWork.setInputData(data.build())
//enque worker
WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(compressionWork.build())


/*** Logic to get Data  ***/
class CompressWorker(context : Context, params : WorkerParameters)
    : Worker(context, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {

        //get Input Data back using "inputData" variable 
        val filePath =  inputData.getString("file_path")

        // Do the work here--in this case, compress the stored images.
        // In this example no parameters are passed; the task is
        // assumed to be "compress the whole library."
        myCompress()

        // Indicate success or failure with your return value:
        return Result.SUCCESS

        // (Returning RETRY tells WorkManager to try this task again
        // later; FAILURE says not to try again.)

    }

}
```

For more information visit this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#params).

Comment: How can I access the data in Worker?

Comment: @Joshua you can use "inputData" to get your data back. Check above sample code. I have explained how to send "file_path" and how to retrieve it back.

Comment: params.getInputData().getString("file_path")

Comment: Is there any way to send non-primitive values as parameter?

Comment: `workDataOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, Any?>): Data` is also provided to use with kotlin extension function `to` like `val data = workDataOf(key to value)`

Comment: To answer @Óscar point here's a discussion on how to pass a Serializable POJO to a Worker https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018299/how-to-pass-pojo-class-in-work-manager-in-android

Comment: @Óscar Be cautious about trying to use `workDataOf`.  Despite its method signature, you can't pass anything other than primitives since the resulting `Data` object can only contain primitives or arrays of primitives.  You will get an `IllegalArgumentException` if you try to pass anything else.

Answer (score 35):

In Java:

Pass params as follow:

```
    Constraints.Builder builder = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED);

    // Passing params
    Data.Builder data = new Data.Builder();
    data.putString("SyncMaster", syncModuleName);

    OneTimeWorkRequest syncWorkRequest =
            new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SyncWorker.class)
                    .addTag("Sync")
                    .setInputData(data.build())
                    .setConstraints(builder.build())
                    .build();

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(syncWorkRequest);
```

You can get like this:

```
public class SyncWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "MyWorker";

    public SyncWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork for Sync");
        String syncTable = getInputData().getString("SyncMaster");
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Hope it will clearly help.