# Check the type of work, it is periodic or on time request?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

So I created a simple Worker class. I would like to start this worker as onTimeWork and Periodic Work as well.

Before WorkManager I used Android Job, and inside the Job there is a dedicated method to decide whetherthe current job is periodic: `params.isPeriodic`

Is there any way to check this in Worker class inside doWork method?

```
**Worker:**
override fun doWork(): Result {
        var workResult = Result.success()

        val isPeriodic = false

        if (isPeriodic) {
          ...
        }

        launch {
            
        }

     return workResult
    }

**Schedules:**

un schedulePeriodicAsync(context: Context) {
            val constraint =
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

            val newMessageWorker =
                PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                    NewMessageWorker::class.java,5,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .setConstraints(constraint)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(
                        BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                        OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    ).build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                DailySyncWorker.TAG,
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE,newMessageWorker)
        }

        fun scheduleNowAsync(context: Context, workCallback: JobCallback? = null) {
            jobCallback = workCallback

            val constraint =
                Constraints.Builder()
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()

            val newMessageWorker =
                OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NewMessageWorker::class.java)
                    .setConstraints(constraint)
                    .setBackoffCriteria(
                        BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                        OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                    )
                    .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniqueWork(
                TAG,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,newMessageWorker)
        }
```

Comment: if there isn't a type available . You can always pass the type [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52639001/how-to-create-a-worker-with-parameters-for-in-workmanager-for-android).

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, if there is no better option, I will use it